# JUnit5: DisableOnDebug replacement?

Tags: timeout, junit5

I'm migrating from JUnit4 to JUnit5. In Junit4 I've used a `Timeout` in conjunction with `DisableOnDebug` like this:

```java
    @Rule
    public TestRule rule = new DisableOnDebug(new Timeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

    @Test
    public void verify_computation_terminates() {
        // Verify that the algorithm can solve a given problem in a reasonable
        // amount of time; relevant for NP problems.
        int result = do_complex_computation();
        assertEquals(42, result);
    }
```

When I debug into `do_complex_computation()`, timeout is disabled - otherwise the debug session would stop.

However, Rules are removed in JUnit5.

How can I get this behaviour in JUnit5 instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it isn't as simple as creating a Rule (unless you consider having to remember to set VM arguments simple).  You can disable the timeouts using a VM argument either only when debugging or always via this option

```
-Djunit.jupiter.execution.timeout.mode=disabled_on_debug
```

Supported options here are *enabled, disabled and disabled_on_debug*

This in documented in the JUnit 5 docs [here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/index.html#writing-tests-declarative-timeouts-mode).

Comment: I don't see why `disabled_on_debug` should not be the default value.

Comment: @Moritz imagine you run with a debugger, but don't set a breakpoint before a deadlock (or infinite loop, or anything else that'd cause the test to run forever) occurs. Then what?

Comment: @cj81499 I see your point. However, I'd argue that I would simply manually terminate the test if I failed to set my breakpoints properly and retry. I can hardly imagine a use case for having a timeout in debug mode.

Comment: @Moritz, fair enough. I intended to point out that the chosen default is likely more predictable (albeit, less useful). If you think the default should be changed, I suggest you open a feature request!